# Error when starting Redis server: "Address already in use"

Tags: process, ruby, redis

I am trying to install redis, according to the instructions here : https://redis.io/download, but getting the error :

> Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already
>   in use

when I run command `ps -ef|grep redis`
i see :

```
nomi      1168   947  0  2434 ?        00:00:00 grep --color=auto redis
```

I type `kill 1168` where 1168 is my PID and the process is not killed:

> "bash: kill: (1168) - No such process"

next time i run the command `ps -ef|grep redis` i get diffrent PID number for example :
1170

How can I remove this process?

Comment: The output of your `ps -ef | grep redis` is simply showing the grep command, not a `redis` process.  By the time you try to kill it, it has already stopped running.  It appears that you have some other process listening to power 6379.  Try `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` to see what is using that port.

Comment: I tried to run "sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN" : but nothing appears

Comment: Try `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 6379` to check if something is attached to that particular socket

Comment: no nothing is attached.

Comment: How about `netstat -tulpn`

Comment: it displays an empty table, I even tried to restart my computer and only run  "redis" but still the same error

Comment: This seems very strange - you may need to use 'sudo' to see the program names, but the netstat should show connections from dhclient, systemd-resolv and avahi-daemon at least.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this same problems, but I forgot that redis persists. If you get this error, try this command:

```
redis-cli ping
```

And this solved my issue:

```
[root@tannetto tannetto]# ps -ef |grep redis
root      4871  4836  0 11:07 pts/0    00:00:00 grep redis
redis     4995     1  0 Jun23 ?        04:21:50 /usr/bin/redis-server *:6379
```

After finding redis, `kill -9` it!

```
[root@tannetto tannetto]# kill -9 4995
[root@tannetto tannetto]# service redis restart
Stopping redis-server:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting redis-server:                                     [  OK  ]
[root@tannetto tannetto]# service redis status
redis-server (pid  4919) is running...
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , But I also had to install sudo apt-get install redis-server

Answer (score 5):

`sudo service redis-server stop`

Comment: so easy and it worked thanks!